# What is an easy way of removing a list of words from a list of sentences?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of stop words which I'd like to remove from every string in a list containing sentences. I wrote a short piece of code which replaces any occurrence of the stop words with a blank string, but, obviously, this removes the string *anywhere* it appears, even if that is in the middle of a word.

```
# Remove stop words from sentenceList
for i in sentenceList:
    for word in stopWords:
        i = i.replace(word.rstrip("\n"), "")
```

I've searched around for a while and can't find an obvious solution.

What is the most simple method of removing the strings *only* when they are surrounded by spaces or have a full stop or other punctuation afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` and word boundaries. Word boundaries will ensure a match occurs only between a word character (roughly a through z, 0 through 9 and underscore) and a non-word character (everything not mentioned before).

```
i = re.sub(r"\b" + re.escape(word.rstrip("\n")) + r"\b", "", i)
```

I'm using `re.escape` in case you have regex metacharacters in your word, though that's unlikely if your word has only letters, but better be safe than sorry.